# How to install two versions of linux on two separate hard drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a system with two 1Tb and one 2Tb hard drives, the first 1Tb disk has Ubuntu16.04.6LTS and I want to install Ubuntu20LTS on the second 1Tb disk. I made a bootable USB and from boot menu chose to boot from the USB. At `allocate drive space` chose `something else` and in `Installation type` window, chose the second drive `/dev/sdb`.

Followed steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) and partitioned my `/dev/sdb` into `/dev/sdb1(type swap)`, `/dev/sdb5(type ext4, mount point /)` and `/dev/sdb6(type ext4, mount point /home)`, I hope none of this is messing with whatever is on `dev/sda`?

After this, if I select `dev/sdb` for boot loader installation it says it will erase `partition #5 of SCSI(0,0,0)(sda) as swap` apart from `sdb`'s partitions. Is this okay, it won't affect ubuntu on `sda`?

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232958/installing-ubuntu-20-04-not-alongside-ubuntu-16-04) suggests removing the disk with old ubuntu first, and then proceeding, but I don't think I can do that.

[image: sdb]
[image: sda]

Comment: Ubuntu stopped needing/wanting swap partition around 18.04, using a swap file now.  Try it without the swap partition and you might want to double check the sizes of partition / and /home, they are about 20GBs in size in the picture( I like more)

Comment: @crip659 ya I'll change the sizes, but the main issue is it tries to erase the swap partition in old disk, which has ububtu16, so I'm worried if that will mess with the old installation. Should I still go ahead, I guess swap has RAM stuff so I'm guessing shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: Swap is just for aiding computers with small ram amounts and /or hibernation.  Does not contain data.  Don't know enough to give you a correct answer, but think having 20.04 doing it is better than you or I just deleting it ourselves.  Can google removing swap partition for another answer.

Comment: If you allow the swap partition on sda to be deleted you will probably get some error messages if you try to boot the 16.04 installation. I doubt it will be fatal but you can probably avoid it by changing to a swap file before installing 20.04.

Comment: just here confirming that erasing swap didn't cause any issue. Both installations work fine.